# Regex in SQLite and ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have an app that is acting like a dictionary and now I need a bit help.

I would like to use regex in SQLite when trying to find words, but regex is user function so it's not supported directly by SQLite.

The idea is that app should find all words that are created from letters for example 'a e b i p' and it should return words like babe, abe, pie, etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

So to be more clear, I would like to do a select statement with like that returns all words containing letters a, e, b, i and p but not to be limited on word length, so that I receive word be as well as die and pie even if letter b i is not present in those last two.

Sorry for inconvenience I caused with not properly formulated question.

Comment: Looks to me like Apple only did a half-assed embedding of SQLite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `GLOB`?

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE wordname GLOB "*[aebip]*"
```

Comment: It's working same as several like '%letter%' statements, returning all words that contains one or more letters while I need it to return words containing all of these letters. In a dictionary with 0.5 million words that is overkill specially on iPhone. Tnx for help anyway.

Comment: Ah ok, maybe you should make that more clear in the question as i interpreted the question as searching for letters a, e, b, i and p should return "babe", "abe" and "pie".

Comment: Yes, maybe I should. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: This was the closest answer to my question, now I will filter results returned by GLOB with NSPredicate or on some other way. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use the UNION operator (which would remove duplicate rows).

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE wordname LIKE '%a%'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE wordname LIKE '%b%'
....
```

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't that return all records that have letter a and letter b in them? I'm more after to get all words with combinations of letters above. As it now seems I would need to use Core Data and NSPredicate instead of SQLite or with SQLite in background.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE wordname LIKE '%a%' 
AND wordname LIKE '%e%' 
AND wordname LIKE '%b%' 
AND wordname LIKE '%i%' 
AND wordname LIKE '%p%'
```

Comment: Hmm, you cannot use like because it's excluding results. It should return all possible words from the database with combinations of the letters above. So if you write select statement with like then you will exclude words that doesn't contain all letters in like statement.

Comment: Then maybe you could use OR operator.

Comment: Then it would be enormous query because I would have to write select * from tablename where wordname like '%a'% and wordname like '%b%' or wordname like '%a%' and wordname like '%b%' and wordname like '%c%' etc

Comment: If there is an index on wordname column, then the query won't be enormous